# How to set values to extjs datepicker when clicking on a button?

Tags: extjs

I want to set yesterday value to my datepicker

```
items: [
    {
        title: 'Start Date',
        margin: '0 20 0 0',
        header: {
            titleAlign: 'center'
        },
        items: {
            xtype: 'datepicker',
            itemId: 'startDate',
            value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
            showToday: false,
            handler: function (picker, date)
            {
                var endDate = picker.up('form').down('#endDate').getValue();
                var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((endDate.getTime() - date.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
            }
        }
    }
]
```

using button

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    cls: 'datePickerSearchBtn',
    text: 'Yesterday',
    listeners: {
        click: function () {}
    }
}
```

How can i do that?

Comment: want to set yesterday value to my datepicker using button how can i do that help me out

Comment: Please format your question. Do not leave it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Ext.picker.Date.setValue()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.picker.Date.html#method-setValue) method, like this

```
datepicker.setValue(Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1));
```

Check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27ga).